# Delete character in C

Tags: c, function, pointers

Say I have the following code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void f0(char* str){
    printf(" it riii%sght,",str);
}

void f1(char* str){
    printf("Congr%sats,",str);
}

void f2(char* str){
    printf(" you gg%sot",str);
}

int main(){

    return 0;
}
```

And I  want it to print out "Congrats, you got it right". Is there a way to write a function in less than 4 lines of code that can get ride of extra characters? I thought that maybe I would have to use the delete character that is 127 in ASCII. So for example I tried to do:

`char del = 127;`

`char* del_ptr = &del;`

`f2(del_ptr);`

and pass it as an argument to a function just to delete one character. This didn't work however. Is there a way that I can add one and only one function with no more than 4 lines of code, write at most 3 lines of code in main function and include at most 3 libraries that produces, "Congrats, you got it right"?

I also want to know why passing the delete character as an argument to these functions also doesn't work.

Comment: It seems very hard to understand what you intend to do. Anyways, if you would like to printf `Congrats, you got is right` just use `printf("Congrats, you got is right");` It can't get more simple than that.

Comment: If you think emitting a del-char into your output stream will do what you're apparently thinking, you may be in for a surprise.

Comment: (What´s about ASCII 8 ?)

Comment: Q: What do you want to do: 1) delete characters from the C string, or 2) delete characters that have been printed to the screen?  They're completely different, you know :)

Comment: I have 3 functions that each contain part of that sentence. I have someone combine them using the restrictions I said above to print out "Congrats, you got it write". Obviously in each `printf` statement there are extra characters in front of the `%s` that need to somehow be removed in order to get a correct solution.

Comment: "Removed" ... or "Overwritten"?  Look at [SetConsoleCursorPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686025%28v=vs.85%29.aspx]) (nee "gotoxy()" in many ancient, DOS-era compilers).

Comment: Even if this worked like this, surely you would want a backspace character, not delete, in this case? :P

Comment: ...which is ASCII 8. Funny that everyone seems to either repeat or ignore it :) @All: Why everything have to make sense? It´s probably an assignment...there are some "funny" teachers out there.

Comment: The word is "right", you don't want either "backspace" or "delete" control characters, and [don't call me surely](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0A5t5_O8hdA)

Answer (score 1):

This is of course more than 4 lines in total but will work if you include this in your main method.

```
int main() {
    char del = 8; //8 is the backspace character in ASCII
    char ptr[3] = "\0";
    f1(ptr);
    ptr[0] = del;
    ptr[1] = '\0';
    f2(ptr);
    ptr[1] = del;
    ptr[2] = '\0';
    f0(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

This can then be optimized to fit the requirements of max lines of code and as this seems to be a puzzle or homework of some type I'll let you work that part out.

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(){
    f1("");
    f2("\b");
    f0("\b\b");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to be a smart ass.  I'm assuming this is a trick question handed to you for some interviewer who is testing your ability to think.  It's one of those common aptitude questions in code form.

> Aim: write a function in less than 4 lines of code that prints out
>   "Congrats, you got is right".

3 lines?

```
void f3(){
    printf("Congrats, you got is right\n");
}
```

The question doesn't ask you to make it work, it never tells you to finish main so this should be a pass.

---

I think BLUEPIXY has it right... but seeing as you said you had to write a function to do it... a more correct version of that would be.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void f0(char* str){
    printf(" it riii%sght,",str);
}

void f1(char* str){
    printf("Congr%sats,",str);
}

void f2(char* str){
    printf(" you gg%sot",str);
}

void f3(){
  f1("");
  f2("\b");
  f0("\b\b");
}

int main(){
    f3();
    return 0;
}
```

This works correctly under Linux... meets the 3 line function (body part at least) and less than 4 lines added to main.  No special libraries needed.

Anyway, it's a useless piece of code... no one in their right mind would write code this bad unless they thinking of entering the [International Obfuscated C Code](http://www.ioccc.org/) contest.

Comment: I don't doubt it is testing our ability to be a little bit clever and think. I'm a student at a college and this was a homework assignment that we had. Had to think outside of the box a little bit, but I wish it were that easy that. The real assignment had more functions with more characters to delete so my solution I provided was the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is in dire need of a solution, I figured this out last week and forgot to share it.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void f0(char* str){
    printf(" it riii%sght,",str);
}

void f1(char* str){
    printf("Congr%sats,",str);
}

void f2(char* str){
    printf(" you gg%sot",str);
}

void f5(void (*f_ptr)(char*), int x){
    char str[3] = {8,8,8};
    str[x] = '\0';
    f_ptr(str);  
}

int main(){
    void (*f_array[3])(char *) = {f1, f2, f0};     
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        f5(f_array[i], i);
}
```